# Prime Faces Collector Adding in the reverse order

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using prime faces collector component and when the user is adding an item to the list, it is adding the record to the end of the list. Is there any easy way of adding the item to the top of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply reverse a list in java itself like this.

XHTML

```
<p:collector value="#{createBookBean.book}"   
                        addTo="#{createBookBean.books}" />
```

MANAGED BEAN

```
   private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(); 

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
           **Collections.reverse(this.books);**
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}
```

Comment: In JSF a getter or a setter can be called multiple times since the browser creates multiple requests to load a page. This will reverse the collection multiple times and can lead to strange results.

Answer (score 1):

When you add items to binded list you can use `.add(0, item)` in your managed bean. It will add desired items at start of the collection.

```
private List<Item> listItems = new ArrayList<Item>(); 

public void onAddListItem(){
   listItems.add(0, new Item());
}
```